# FFMPEG RTMP streaming to WOWZA server with credentials

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, wowza

I would like to stream my webcam using FFMPEG (on Windows) to a Wowza server.
The Wowza server has several applications defined. 
Each has its own credentials (user name and password).

I'm using the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -s 512x288 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1024k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://<wowza server address>:1935/appname/streamname
```

Yet the Wowza server fails to get the stream.
What am I missing here?
Should I add the credentials to Wowza's applications? If so, what is the URL format that will allow me to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly missing the credentials?

Comment: Ofcourse Im commenting on it too late . however my recent study has concluded the fact that authentication on incoming source on rtmp stream is  not possible on non wowza supported encoders . you can see that the server side modules given by Wowza like RTMPAuthenticate , ModuleOnConnectAuthenticate2 etc also add the descriptive phrase "Authenticates RTMP in Flash " and do not give a opensource lib supported url such as ffmpeg for example to test the application .

Answer (score 3):

Replace the url with this

> rtmp://username:password@:1935/appname/streamname

Comment: You forgot the server name, should be:  "rtmp://username:password@<wowza server address>:1935/appname/streamname"